# Preciso de diferentes formas de reorganizar caracteres dentro de uma string, como faço isso?

Tags: c#, c, string, algoritmo

Gostaria de respostas em C, C#, ou apenas um algoritmo, mas de preferencia uma implementação já na linguagem C# porque é o que ando usando.

Por exemplo, suponhamos que eu tenha que descobrir se um número é lido da mesma forma em ambos os sentidos - um exercício bobo de programação que nunca consigo resolver.

```
4004
```

Imaginei que poderia fazer o seguinte:

1. Converto para string.
2. Coloco a string em um array de caracteres.
3. Usando uma função apropriada descubro o tamanho do array.
4. Crio outro array do mesmo tamanho.
5. Copio bytes do `array1` para o `array2`, na ordem inversa (posição 0 em `array1` se torna última de `array2`, posição 1 se torna penúltima, etc...)
6. Comparo as strings resultantes, se forem iguais o número é um palíndromo.

Penso que isso funcione, mas além de não saber como fazer isso na linguagem, acho que deve existir alguma maneira mais simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, utilize o reverse para converter a string em um array ao contrário e compare com o valor original.

```
public bool EhPalindromo(string text)
{
     var reverseText = string.Join("", text.ToLower().Reverse());
     return reverseText == text;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Não precisa ficar mexendo no texto, basta comparar cada caractere iniciando do primeiro com o último, depois o segundo com o penúltimo e assim por diante. Precisa comparar só até a metade já que a comparação depois da metade apenas repetiria o que foi comparado de forma inversa:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(EhPalindromo("4004"));
        WriteLine(EhPalindromo("4002"));
    }
    public static bool EhPalindromo(string texto) {
        //Inicia no final e vai até a metade do final
        for (int i = texto.Length - 1; i > texto.Length / 2; i--) {
            //compara o caractere atual com o inverso dele
            if (texto[i] != texto[texto.Length - i - 1]) {
                //encontrou uma diferença, pode encerrar sabendo que não bate
                return false;
            }
        }
        //se chegou até aqui é porque houve coincidência total
        return true;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JQSjNr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lE0XnH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Palindrome.cs).

Certamente poderia ter sido feito com um código mais simples usando algo pronto mas acredito que a pergunta é justamente aprender como fazer um algoritmo que faça manualmente.

Comment: Porquê `texto.Substring(i, 1)` e não `texto[i]`? É mais eficiente comparar o caractér, do que criar e alocar 2*n sub strings. Mais uma coisa, a condição de paragem pode ser `i > texto.Length /2`. E visto que o OP não é experiente nem em programação, nem na linguagem, acho que uma explicação em português do algoritmo ajudaria.

Comment: É que eu me baseei em um algoritmo que eu já tinha em outra linguagem. De fato dá para otimizar.

Answer (score 1):

Certa vez tive que resolver um problema parecido em C, segue o que fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//retonra o tamanho de uma string delimitada por '\0',
//ou oturo caracter < 32 na ASCII.
//Parametro: string a ser verificado o tamanho.
int sizeofString(char* str){
    int i = 0;
    for(i;str[i] >= 32;i++);
    return i;
}

//retorna true(1) caso as duas strings sejam inversas.
//Parametros: str1 e str2 sao as strings a serem analisadas.
int numerosInversos(char* str1, char* str2){
    int tam = sizeofString(str1);
    if(tam != sizeofString(str2))return 0;
    else{
         int i = 0;
         for(i;i<tam;i++)
               if(str1[i] != str2[tam-i-1]) return 0;          
         return 1;      
    }    
}

int main(){
    char num1[10],num2[10];
    strcpy(num1,"4004");

    if(numerosInversos(num1,num1))printf("\nIguais\n");
    else printf("\nDiferentes\n");

    system("pause");    
    return 0;}
```

Sei que em C# existem funções para a transformação de inteiros em strings ([valor inteiro].ToString(), se não me engano).

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo uma alteração na resposta do @Kevin acho que daria mais certo em questões de utilização de strings não numérica também:

```
public bool EhPalindromo(string texto)
{
     var textoAoContrario = String.Join("", texto.ToLower().Reverse());
     return textoAoContrario == texto.ToLower();
}
```

A principal modificação fica por conta do `.ToLower()` na variável `texto` também, tendo em vista que a mesma função é usada no texto reverso.